# Difference about getIIS and refineConflict

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

I'm using cplex to solve a linear programming problem. Since the time of invoking getIIS is long when the size of the problem is large, I try to use refineConflict method
to find the minimal conflict instead. But the result of invoking getIIS and refineConflict is very different. Below is the result of a unsatisfiable linear programming problem.

The result of invoking getIIS:

```
IloRange 3_4 : 0.0 <= (-1.0*water_t_4 + 1.0*water_v_1_4) <= infinity
IloRange 3_4 : 5.0 <= (2.0*water_t_4 + 1.0*water_v_2_4) <= infinity
IloRange 4_5 : 0.0 <= (-1.0*water_v_2_4 - 1.0*water_t_5 + 1.0*water_v_2_5) <= infinity
IloRange 4_5 : 2.0 <= (1.0*water_v_1_4) <= 2.0
IloRange 5_6 : 0.0 <= (1.0*water_v_2_5) <= 0.0
```

The result of invoking refineConflict(the first parameter is the whole linear constraints and the second is a array in which the member is set to 1).

```
Possible : IloRange 4_5 : 2.0 <= (1.0*water_v_1_4) <= 2.0
Possible : IloRange 5_6 : 0.0 <= (1.0*water_v_2_5) <= 0.0
```

I feel confused about the results given by the two methods. 
Here is my code and the version my cplex is cplex_studio125.win-x86-64:

```
cplex=new IloCplex();
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.IntParam.Threads,1);
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.IntParam.RootAlg, IloCplex.Algorithm.Concurrent);
cplex.addRangel()...
if(!cplex.solve){
   IloConstraint[] arr is the whole linear constraints 
    double prefs[] = new double[arr.length];
    Arrays.fill(prefs, 1);
    if(cplex.refineConflict(arr, prefs)){               
      ConflictStatus[] conflicts = cplex.getConflict(arr);
      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < conflicts.length;i1++ ){                 
        if(conflicts[i1]== ConflictStatus.Member)
           System.out.println(" Proved : " + arr[i1]);
        else if (conflicts[i1]==ConflictStatus.PossibleMember)
           System.out.println(" Possible : " + arr[i1]);
      }
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of what you do exactly to get those results. Also, what version of cplex do you use? getIIS seems to be unsupported since version 10.

Comment: The version of my cplex is cplex_studio125.win-x86-64.